# Supremum of a function vs the infimum of its multiplicative version

Tags: convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Given a function $f: R^d \rightarrow R$, I am trying to figure out under what conditions on the function and the set X we have the following:
$$
\inf_{x \in X} f(x) = \frac{1}{\sup_{x \in X} f(x)}.
$$

So far taking

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = 1 \\
                     -1 & x = -1 \\
                      \infty &\text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
$$

is a counter example that I have found, so I think either strict positivity or negativity of a function is a requirement. I think we might also need lower semi continuity but I am not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: I can easily think of a positive $C^{\infty}$ function which violates this. Just think a little more, and also intuitively: is there any reason why the minimum of a function must be equal to the reciprocal of the maximum?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous an obvious sufficient condition on $X$ is, that there is a $r\in \mathbb{R}$,$|r|\geq 1$ s.t. $\overline{X} = f^{-1}\left([\frac{1}{r},r]\right)$, where the overline denotes the closure of the set.